# Create Menu below logo in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, menu

I wanted to create MENU below  logo.

how to create "header menu with "HOME", "ABOUT US", "TESTIMONIALS", "CONTACT US".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CMS Static block (under `CMS -> Static Block` in admin-end) with required links and call this static block in header below logo. 
Below code can be used to call static block in phtml file.

> echo
>   $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();